# How do I allow two apps on Android to open the same file type? i.e. Not have to choose a default

Tags: 8.0-oreo, files, default-applications

We have two applications that run on the Android platform that both use XML files to transfer data. (`Android v8.0.0`)

However when we open either app, the OS always asks "*Which one of these two apps to you want to open this file with by default?*". We don't want to set a default as we need both apps to be able to open XML files as required by their individual function.

Is there a way to tell Android "***This file type can be opened by any app that wants to do so***"?

At the moment we need to go into **App** settings and ***Clear Default*** on each app after we have run it in order for the other app to "*take over*" as default when we run that. Once we have set default  to either app, then the other one throws an error when it tries to open files because it is not the **default** app

That's not really a viable way forward.

Is Android even capable of this file type handling duality? Is there a setting we can change to allow files to be opened by "*non-default*" apps.

Changing the app code is not a short term solution, but if Android truly cannot handle the situation then we may need to, but that will not solve the problem for our users right now. Changing a setting in Android to allow what we want to have happen would be quicker and cleaner.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: While app development is off-topic here, you might want to clarify `However when we open either app, the OS always asks ...` Are you opening the app or opening the file and then that dialog is happening after a list of apps show up?

Comment: Opening either app. Both apps will try to open any XML files waiting to be processed in their own storage area. That's when the argument starts.

Comment: My guess is that your apps are using a third party library or a different app to do file selection. See: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending#StartActivity Behavior is directed by the app selector. If you are using a third-party library you'll have to go back to both apps to change the behavior. If you are using any OEM or third-party File Manager, that is out of your control. Note this sounds like a failure in specs or QA so off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Android can't be configged or rigged to allow this, so it seems like this is purely an app problem.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to assign multiple apps as default for a single file type.

if you open a file, how can a computer know which application YOU want? you can only define **one** default or let the computer ask each time (no default)

Therefore i don't understand the logic of your question

Comment: Thanks for that. We are opening the app rather than the file. The asking to choose a default pops up when the app tries to open an XML file.
I get the feeling we will need to go back to one app developer and get the code changed so Android isn't feeling the conflict.
We don't want to set a default app at all, but Android insists on there being one whenever a file of that type is opened.

Comment: that's definitely some issue with your app. i have two different video players installed. both of them will open mp4 files without asking for default